# file.delete() is not working in Andorid 13 target API level 33

Tags: android

I  am downloading file from API and saving in saving in `///storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Rove-R24K-PRO/Videos/2023_0322_205825_0019.MP4`
I am trying to delete  video from given external storage using below code.

```
boolean b = file.delete();
```

I have checked file exist or not using file.exist() its returning true but when i try to delete file using able code then i am getting b false while i already have given permission  Read and write permission of file can any one please help me in this.
while same code is working below AndroidR .

Comment: You know of [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)  and that you need to use totally different functions for storage access on Android 11+?

Comment: I have not used scoped Storage i have just use Read write external storage permission can you please help me how to do using scoped storage

Comment: It is unclear how you or another app or a manager creates that file. Please tell as all depends on it. Post your code.

Comment: If your app created that file it should be able to delete it.

Comment: Do not only use file.exists() but also file.canWrite() and file.canRead() before you try to write or read or delete.

Comment: its working below Android R but  above that its not working

Comment: ???? I made three comments. You did not react to one of them.

Comment: I have  done using Media Storage API

Comment: @MARSH: did you check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164496/how-to-delete-an-image-in-android-10-scoped-storage-mediastore-entry-file